# How would you pixelate an image in Matlab without using the image toolbox?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

```
mypicture=imread(filename); %inputs 1st image
[row col pan]=size(mypicture);
subplot(2,1,2)
pixpicture=mypicture;
image(pixpicture);
hold on;

for J=1:stepval:row
for K=1:stepval:col
    pix=pixpicture(J,K,:);
    x=[K K+stepval K K+stepval];
    y=[J J J+stepval J+stepval];
    plot(x,y);
    hold all;
end    
end

subplot (2,1,1)
image(mypicture);
end
```

I'm trying to pixelate an image without using the image processing toolbox. I was told the method, which is to take a pixel then color all of the surrounding pixels that color, however I'm having trouble doing this in my code. What I have above is what I've tried however it doesn't quite work as intended.

What are your suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Think of each pixel as three numbers, each corresponding to how much red, green and blue that pixel has. Say pixel=[128 35 0]

You then need to use those three values and assign them to the surrounding pixels.

```
pixpicture(J,K,:)=pix
```

Where the J and K values should correspond to all the neighbors of that pixel.

Give that a go, hopefully I said enough without just giving you the answer.

Having said all of that why don't you just reduce the size of the image using

```
pixelatedImage = imresize(mypicture, scale)
```

It would be much easier than trying to do that yourself. It doesn't look like you gave a thought to the cases where you have corners or how many pixels to change in the neighborhood...

Comment: We actually aren't allowed to use imresize or I would be using it.

Comment: Well in that case let me know if you have any problems/questions with what I said above...